# Php installation errro on windows 10 pro

Tags: php, windows, visual-studio, intelephense

Hello guys I’ve been trying to install and use php extensions on my windows 10 but up to no avail I’ve tried installing the php intelephense but it’s still showing errors but help

Am getting the following errors

Error while installing Php intelephense. Please check the log for more details.

And
Unable to open Extension: Php Intelephense: XHR failed.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PS8Gm.jpg)

Comment: "Please check the log for more details" -- what information does the log contain?

Comment: Thats a VSCode error and NOTHING to do with PHP Installation :)

Comment: Please try to add the error description rather than posting the "image".

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

After you have installed the extension, check the extensions installed **directly** in PHP installation.

Try running these in your command line

```sh
php -r "var_dump(get_loaded_extensions());"
```

```sh
php -r "var_dump(extension_loaded('intelephense'));"
```

or create a new PHP file, `index.php` with contents

```php
<?php
phpInfo();
```

Use these methods to verify whether the extension is trully installed or is missing from your PHP installation.

Answer (score -1):

Do you use short open tags? If so there's a setting for that `intelephense.environment.shortOpenTag`.
Other things to check:

1. Add file associations if your files have a different extension eg `"intelephense.files.associations": ["*.inc"]`.
2. Try with other vscode extensions disabled.
3. Check you haven't excluded files intelephense.files.exclude.
4. Open the file folder instead of just the file.